# Access database with provider

Tags: android, sql, database, provider

Few time ago, I started to work with databases and content providers, and I made a simple app to learn how to work with them.

Now, I'm developing another app that has almost the same functionality that the one I did. I'm trying to implement the same code adapted for the new app, but I'm getting one error that I'm not able to find why is happening.

This is LogCat's output:

```
02-11 10:45:59.014: E/ActivityThread(22665): Failed to find provider info for com.final.reversegeocoding
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.final.reversegeocoding/places
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:913)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at com.final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity.insertPlaces(GeocodingActivity.java:427)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at com.final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity.access$27(GeocodingActivity.java:416)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at com.final.reversegeocoding.GeocodingActivity$6.onClick(GeocodingActivity.java:288)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-11 10:45:59.024: E/AndroidRuntime(22665):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the road that the app follows to save values in the database:

**MainActivity (GeocodingActivity)**

```
private void insertPlaces(String number, String street, String city, String country1, String country2, String lat, String lng){
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(Places.NUMBER, number);
        newValues.put(Places.STREET, street);
        newValues.put(Places.CITY, city);
        newValues.put(Places.COUNTRY1, country1);
        newValues.put(Places.COUNTRY2, country2);
        newValues.put(Places.LAT, lat);
        newValues.put(Places.LNG, lng);

        getContentResolver().insert(PlacesProvider.CONTENT_URI, newValues);
}
```

**ContentProvider (PlacesProvider)**

```
public class PlacesProvider extends ContentProvider {

    /*CONTENT_URI*/
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.final.reversegeocoding";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/places");

    private PlacesDatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    /**UriMatcher*/
    private static final int URI_PLACES = 1;
    private static final int URI_PLACE_ITEM = 2;

    private static final UriMatcher mUriMatcher;
    static {
        mUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "places", URI_PLACES);
        mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "places/#", URI_PLACE_ITEM);
    }


    public class Places implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String NUMBER= "number";
        public static final String STREET= "street";
        public static final String CITY= "city";
        public static final String COUNTRY1= "country1";
        public static final String COUNTRY2= "pacountry2s";
        public static final String LAT = "latitude";
        public static final String LNG = "longitude";
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new PlacesDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {

        database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = database.insert(PlacesDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Uri result = null;

        if (id >= 0){
            result = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just forgot to declare the provider in the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name=".database.PlacesProvider"
    android:authorities="com.final.reversegeocoding"
    android:multiprocess="true" />
```